# como soluciono el error del report viewer en visual studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, reportviewer

Error: Un error ocurrió durante el proceso del reporte local.
La definición del reporte 'Incluir\Impresiones\Reportw.rdlc' no es válida.
La definición de este informe no es válida ni es compatible con esta versión de Reporting Services.
Es posible que la definición del informe se haya creado con una versión posterior de Reporting Services o que contenga contenido que no esté bien formado o que no sea válido según los esquemas de Reporting Services.
Detalles: la definición del informe tiene un espacio de nombres de destino no válido 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' que no se puede actualizar.

Cuando tenia VS2012 lo podia editar sin problema pero ahora actualice a VS2019 y cuando edite un reporte y quise mostrarlo en el reporteviewer me sale ese error, como lo soluciono?

En mi web.config tengo:

```html
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <!--<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>-->
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
          
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <!--<add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>-->
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <!--<add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />-->
      <!--<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>-->
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939582/i-can-not-get-the-report-viewer-to-work-on-vs-2019

Comment: Y esto tambien: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUlRTZMiWLg